# Directed graphs - notation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, notation

In one article I found the following notation without explanation, only statement that it is "the usual one in graph theory".

Let $e$ be a edge in directed graph and suppose that $v$ is vertex in this graph. Then authors use notation $v\in t(e)$ and (in another place) $v\in s(e)$. From the context I know that it should mean "$v$ is the begining of $e$" and "$v$ is the end of $e$", but I don't know which one has first meaning and which the second one. I tried to found this notation in many places but without success. I suppose $s$ and $t$ are abbreviations, but I don't have any idea from which words it follows. (is $s(e)$ a **s**tarting point ?)

Comment: The author should have explained the first time he or she uses the notation. I'd guess "s" for "starting" and "t" for "terminating".

Comment: I agree with @EthanBolker. I've worked with directed graphs quite a bit and have not seen this notation before.

Comment: Ok. I would check previous articles on this subject given by these authors. In an article which I read there is neither explanation nor reference where the explanation can be found. Only information that it is "standard notation". (maybe "standard" means "used by authors in any place" :) ). From the context I'm sure it is one of the meanings which I wrote. Explanation given by @EthanBolker seems meaningfully.

Comment: I think this notation is standard when studying flow networks, where $s$ is often the source and $t$ the sink.  What is non-standard is considering a single edge to be a flow network, but that would agree with @EthanBolker's interpretation.

Comment: @Shagnik If $s$ is source then $t$ may be target.

Comment: @EthanBolker That would make sense, and perhaps it was originally so, but by now "sink" is standard terminology - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most books I've seen on flow/algorithms use s to be the starting point and t to be the target of the given edge. It is strange, however, that this was expected to be trivially understood, as it's not the notation across the board.